# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

got this error and really don't get why..
I'm trying to display events on angular-calendar : https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/async-events

> error_handler.ts:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
>   undefined
>       at MapSubscriber.project (planning.component.ts:100)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:80)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:99)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.85.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-mix.js:424)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:280)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.85.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-mix.js:423)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.85.Zone.runTask (zone-mix.js:191)

*component.ts*

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomDateFormatter } from './custom-date-formatter.provider';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface Event {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 start: string;
 end: string;
}

events$: Observable<Array<CalendarEvent<{ event: Event }>>>;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchEvents();
}

fetchEvents(): void {

    this.events$ = this.http
        .get(this.apiUrl)
        .map((response) => response.json())
        .map(({ results }: { results: Event[] }) => {
            return results.map((event: Event) => {
                return {
                    title: event.title,
                    start: new Date(event.start),
                    end: new Date(event.end),
                    color: colors.yellow
                };
            });
        });

}
```

*json data from api*

```
[
{
"id": 2,
"user_id": 1,
"planning_id": 1,
"start": "2017-09-03T22:00:00.000Z",
"end": "2017-09-06T12:33:46.271Z",
"title": "A 3 day event",
"created_at": "2017-09-05 16:39:47",
"updated_at": "2017-09-05 16:39:47"
},
{
"id": 3,
"user_id": 1,
"planning_id": 1,
"start": "2017-09-03T22:00:00.000Z",
"end": "2017-09-06T12:33:46.271Z",
"title": "A 3 day event",
"created_at": "2017-09-07 13:27:36",
"updated_at": "2017-09-07 13:27:36"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's old but I found a way to make it work with Angular 5

Declare the events this way:

```
asyncEvents$: Observable<CalendarEvent[]>;
```

Then load your data with HttpClient

Note that I have a `DateEvent` returned by my API

```
loadEvents() {
    this.asyncEvents$ = this.http.get<DateEvent[]>(YOUR_URL) 
      .map(res => { 
        return res.map(event => { 
          return {
              title: event.label,
              start: new Date(event.startDate),
              color: {primary: event.color, secondary: "#D1E8FF"},
              meta: {
                event
              },
              allDay: true
            };
        });
      });
  }
```

Then everything works as expected

Comment: I get `TypeError: res.map is not a function at MapSubscriber.eval`

Comment: Be sure that you import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

Comment: Yes is imported. My issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645426/angular-calendar-async-http-map-of-undefined) for more details

Answer (score 1):

1. **ng update**
2. **ng update @angular/cli**
3. **ng update @angular/core**

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the map operator:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Yes, it was done. Thanks for the precision I added it in the example.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this problem. I have searched some alternatives who works but for my curiosity i would like to know the cause of this one.

Comment: @mchev have you found the solution? my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645426/angular-calendar-async-http-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `node_module` and run `npm install`. Its solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to upgrade the `typescript` from `typescript@3.x.x` to `typescript@4.x.x`.

How this error come? I upgraded my angular app from `angular@10` to `angular@11`.