# Angular calendar async http 'map' of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http, angular-calendar

I try to install the angular calendar in my app, I have the data of the events in the database, but when I try to call them I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at MapSubscriber.eval
```

The original code is here: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/async-events

My **component.ts**:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConsultaService } from '../../services/consulta/consulta.service';
import { Consulta } from '../../models/consulta.model';

//calendar imports
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {
  /* ... */
} from 'date-fns';

const colors: any = {
  /* ... */
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turnos',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './turnos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turnos.component.min.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TurnosComponent implements OnInit {

  activeDayIsOpen: boolean = false;
  view: string = 'month';
  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  events$: Observable<Array<CalendarEvent<{ consulta: Consulta }>>>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public _consultaService: ConsultaService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchEvents();
  }

  fetchEvents(): void {
    const getStart: any = {
      month: startOfMonth,
      week: startOfWeek,
      day: startOfDay
    }[this.view];

    const getEnd: any = {
      month: endOfMonth,
      week: endOfWeek,
      day: endOfDay
    }[this.view];

    this.events$ = this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/consulta')
      .pipe(
        map(({ results }: { results: any[] }) => {
          return results.map((consulta: any) => { // <--- error line
            return {
              title: consulta.tratamiento_c,
              start: new Date(consulta.date_a),
              color: colors.yellow,
              meta: {
                consulta
              }
            };
          });
        })
      );
  }

  dayClicked({
    /* ... */
  }

  eventClicked(event: CalendarEvent<{ consulta: Consulta }>): void {
    /* ... */
  }

}
```

When I use the `.get` example works well, it shows me all the data. But when I change the url and remove the parameters, by my url `http://localhost:3000/consulta` it does not work in the same way, the calendar is not rendered and throws the `map` error and as you can see, the map is included above.

Adding, my `consulta.service.ts` has this function to bring all the data. How could I subscribe and display the data as the example using my service?

```
  cargarConsultas() {
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/consulta';

    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

I hope you can guide me to the solution. Thanks!

### UPDATE

I changed the line

`map(({ results }: { results: any[] }) => {`

for

`map(( results: Consulta[] ) => {`

and now I get the data from http, but new error appears:

`ERROR TypeError: results.map is not a function`

The error continues referring to the line that you mark in the code above

Comment: Can you show th e structure of the returned json?

Comment: @David mmm thanks for making me see that, I'm getting `undefined` :S

Comment: It should look like this: [image](https://k50.kn3.net/C52C08FB4.png)

Comment: @David I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for updated question**

That's because the json returned by the webservice is no an array of `Consulta`, but an object which `consultats` properties is an array. So, in your subscribe, `results` is not an array

You need to map (using observable's map method) the returned value from the htpp call to an array

```
cargarConsultas() : Observable<Consulta[]> 
{
   let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/consulta';
   return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.consultas);
}
```

Or you can directly access the correct property in the subscribe method

```
cargarConsultas() {
 let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/consulta';
 return this.http.get(url);
}

map(( results: any ) => 
{
return results.consultas.map(
```

**Answer for original question**

If you declare the map parameter like you originally did, this means that the http call returns an object, with a `result` property which if an array

```
 map(({ results }: { results: any[] })
```

From the json you provided, this is not the case. The `consultas` property contains the array. So it should be:

```
 map(({ consultas }: { consultas: Consulta[] }) => {
      return consultas.map((consulta: Consulta)  => {
        return {
          title: consulta.tratamiento_c,
```

Comment: 1 day installing angular-calendar, 15min installing ng-fullcalendar with positive results. Anyway, I will test your code later and I will see that the library is more powerful. Thank you !