# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined When trying to use cache to get details

Tags: angular

I am implementing ProductCache, but it's throwing following error,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Code:

```
  private ProductsCache: any[] = [];

  getAllProducts(accountId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.ProductsApiService.GetAllProducts(accountId, false).map((Products) => {
      this.ProductsCache = Products;
      return Products;
    });
  }

  getProductDetailsById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    if(this.ProductsCache.length < 1) {
      this.getAllProducts(this.AccountApiService.getAccountId()).subscribe((Products: any) => { 
        let ProductDetails = Products.find(x => x.id === Number(id));
        return Observable.of(ProductDetails);
      });
    } else{
      let ProductDetails = this.ProductsCache.find(x => x.id === Number(id));
      return Observable.of(ProductDetails);
    }
  }
```

All I want is to get productdetails by id, if cache is not present then get it before returning details. Using Angular 4.3.0

Answer (score 1):

map it's pipe method

```
getAllProducts(accountId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.ProductsApiService.GetAllProducts(accountId, false)
        .pipe(
             map((Products) => {
                 this.ProductsCache = Products;
                 return Products;
             })
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.ProductsApiService.GetAllProducts(accountId, false)` is probably undefined.

You should get the response object and should matches with the modal you're expecting it.

Comment: have you added import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; ?

Comment: getting all products correctly, this method still works

Comment: Have you gone through 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112408/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined?rq=1
?